# HTTP Handler and Resteasy Deployment with undertow and resteasy

Tags: resteasy, wildfly, undertow

I am trying to run both HTTPServer and also the REST Handler. Only one works at a time not able to make it work both at same time. I need to serve html pages and also the api.

here is my code.

```
    public class HttpServer {

    private final UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer();
    private static String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    private final Undertow.Builder serverBuilder;

    public HttpServer(Integer port, String host) {
        serverBuilder = Undertow
                .builder()
                .addHttpListener(port, host)
                .setHandler(
                        Handlers.path().addPrefixPath(
                                "/",
                                Handlers.resource(
                                        new FileResourceManager(new File(
                                                rootPath + "/web"), 100))
                                        .addWelcomeFiles(
                                                rootPath + "/web/index.html")));
        server.start(serverBuilder);
    }

    public DeploymentInfo deployApplication(String appPath,
            Class<? extends Application> applicationClass) {
        ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
        deployment.setApplicationClass(applicationClass.getName());
        return server.undertowDeployment(deployment, appPath);
    }

    public void deploy(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) throws ServletException {
        server.deploy(deploymentInfo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException {
        HttpServer myServer = new HttpServer(8080, "0.0.0.0");

        DeploymentInfo di = myServer
                .deployApplication("/rest", MyApplication.class)
                .setClassLoader(HttpServer.class.getClassLoader())
                .setContextPath("/my").setDeploymentName("My Application");
        myServer.deploy(di);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [UndertowJaxrsServer](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/server-adapters/resteasy-undertow/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/undertow/UndertowJaxrsServer.java) is overriding the filehandler of your builder:

```java
public UndertowJaxrsServer start(Undertow.Builder builder)
{
    server = builder.setHandler(root).build();
    server.start();
    return this;
}
```

Seems like there is no way to pass another handler to the UndertowJaxrsServer. Possible workarounds might be:

- Deploy another application with one resource class which simply serves files.
- Use the blank Undertow and loose the comfort of easy JAX-RS deployments.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. How could I "Use the blank Undertow and loose the comfort of easy JAX-RS deployments"?

Comment: For first workaround "Deploy another application with one resource class which simply serves files.", how would this work? If run two applications, they will listen to different port numbers, right?

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.1.0.Beta2 and higher you can try this

```
UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer();

ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();

deployment.setApplicationClass(ExampleApplication.class.getName());

DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = server.undertowDeployment(deployment, "/");
deploymentInfo.setClassLoader(MyServer.class.getClassLoader());

deploymentInfo.setContextPath("/api");

server.deploy(deploymentInfo);

server.addResourcePrefixPath("/",
        resource(new PathResourceManager(Paths.get(STATIC_PATH),100)).
            addWelcomeFiles("index.html"));

server.start();
```

RestEasy app will be available at /api/* and static files at /*