# Use Undertwo web server to serve both static pages and web service

Tags: resteasy, undertow

I am trying to use Undertow to serve both static pages and web service (RestEasy) but couldn't get both of them working the same time. I see others asking the same questions like [HTTP Handler and Resteasy Deployment with undertow and resteasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382519/http-handler-and-resteasy-deployment-with-undertow-and-resteasy). There has to be a way to get this work, right? WildFly can handle both on the same port. But how could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
    .setClassLoader(App.class.getClassLoader())
    .setContextPath("/api")
    .setDeploymentName("test.war")
    .addServlets(
        servlet("MessageServlet", MessageServlet.class)
            .addInitParam("message", "Hello World")
            .addMapping("/*"),
        servlet("MyServlet", MessageServlet.class)
            .addInitParam("message", "MyServlet")
            .addMapping("/myservlet"));
DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();
HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();


Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
    .setHandler(Handlers.path()

        // REST API path
        .addPrefixPath("/servlet", servletHandler)

        // Serve all static files from a folder
        .addPrefixPath("/static", new ResourceHandler(
            new PathResourceManager(Paths.get("/path/to/www/"), 100))
            .setWelcomeFiles("index.html"))

    ).build().start();
```

The servlet part is taken from Undertow's official examples, [here](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/undertow/examples/servlet/ServletServer.java).
You can talk to your Message servlets via:

`GET /servlet/api`

`POST /servlet/api/myservlet`